# bootstrap-filestyle jQuery plugin takes a second longer to render

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the word "second" loosely here. I use the Bootstrap CSS along with a few other jQuery components with one of them being bootstrap-filestyle. I see that the form renders fine eventually but I can just about see the vanilla browse button along with the "no file selected" label before it gets replaced with the jQuery component.

I don't see this issue in Chrome (seems fast enough) but can reproduce this in Firefox/Safari (less obvious in the latter).

Some details:

- This is in the development sandbox
- Running puma server locally
- This is in a Rails app
- The JavaScript files are all loaded via the Assets Pipeline (no CDN).
- The app uses Backbone.js with Handlebars as the templating engine.

What could cause this?

Comment: You need to supply us with more information (browser, local or remote server, an snippet of how your loading the files, etc.) , from what I can assume from your information provided is your loading jQuery files from an outside source. Possibly your DOM is loading quicker than your jQuery file, does it happen every time you load this page?

Comment: Thanks arinh. I've updated the question. Hope it has the information that you are looking for. And yes, it happens every time I load the page (issue is consistent).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in development mode with each request your Rails application will reload all the resources which can increase the load-time.

You could merge all Javascript and CSS into a single file by disabling asset debugging. That way you'll only have two requests from JS and CSS.

This can be done in ***config/development.rb***:

```
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = false #true
```

You could also check out any front-end frameworks such as AngularJS, EmberJS, etc. to optimize your application.

However this shouldn't be a problem in production!

Comment: Thanks Arinh. I actually have had this set to "false" even in dev mode for a while (since I didn't want to run into issues like this). I still see the problem but hopefully, this won't occur in prod?

Comment: Development is definitely ***slower***, because it reloads all components. Production mode only loads the components when the server is started.